# Getting skipped whitespases in ANTLR parser

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have some grammar, that ignores whitespaces in following way

```
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

It's ok, 'cos whitespace isn't part of my grammar. But in parser I need to know where whitespaces was. For now I unable to find any straight way to do this.

I use last version of ANTLR4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in v3 you would do something like that if you're looking for a token while parsing the tree:

```
getPreviousTokenInHiddenChannel(retval, input);
public String getPreviousTokenInHiddenChannel(TreeRuleReturnScope retval, TreeNodeStream input) {
try {
    TokenStream tstream = input.getTokenStream();
    CommonTree node = (CommonTree) retval.start;
    int boundary = node.getTokenStopIndex();
    if (boundary <= 0) { // fix for antlr 3.3 bug, from 3.5 getTokenStartIndex should itself resolve parent's boundaries if <= 0
        while (node.getTokenStartIndex() == -1) { // if node is imaginary
          node = (CommonTree) node.getParent(); 
          if (node == null) return ""; // means we are root
          boundary = node.getTokenStopIndex();
          if (boundary > 0) break;   
        }
      } 
    int i = boundary;
    while (true) {
      i--;
      Token tok = tstream.get(i); 
      if (tok.getChannel() == HIDDEN) {
        // do what you want to do https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgRBkjgXHro
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // handle e
  }
}
```

You can easily adapt that piece of code for v4 with something like that (pseudocode):

```
BufferedTokenStream bts;
// retrieve bts
List<Token> hiddenTokens = bts.getHiddenTokensToLeft(bts.index(), HIDDEN);
// loop backwards over the list 
for (int i = hiddenTokens.size(); i--; i >= 0) {
    Token t = hiddenTokens.get(i)
    // process your hidden token
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Token stream API](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BufferedTokenStream.html#getHiddenTokensToLeft%28int%29)

You must get used to looking at the API and source code. You can also buy the book cheaply. Page 206: Accessing Hidden Channels.